# array elements push in android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which can contain 3 elements.
Now after adding first 3 elements whenever i want to add another elements it will be added in the last position(3) and the element of first position will be out of the list.
For example:

```
 i add "a","b","c" in the list
               a
               b
               c
   then if i want to add "d" in the list               
               b
               c
               d

   then if i want to add "e" in the list 
               c
               d
               e
```

........so on

How can i do this in android???
Can anyone help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the task by following code:

```
add.set(0,add.get(1));
add.set(1,add.get(0));
add.set(2,newElement);
```

after you have inserted first three element.

Comment: in terms of complexity, this is terrible. also, it does not work (you probably means `add.get(2)`)

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say. Why wont it work?

Comment: What happens if the list has 4,5,6,7, ... 1000,.. items in the future? It is hard to maintain.

Comment: I answered the question as it was needed. I understand its not dynamic if he wants dynamic he can simply put a for loop with arraylist size and replace the integers.Anyway thanks for ur comments

Comment: @Rujul1993: simply try it. you'll that after the full example from the OP, your list contains `b, b, e`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the stock API that I know of. You can easily create your own using one of the approaches described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java).