# How to implement a queue where the first-in item is automatically popped out when full?

Tags: java, collections, queue

I am tracking a list of colors. I only need to worry about the last two colors added to this list. So this queue should be a fixed size (of 2).

```
    queue.add(color1);
    queue.add(color2);
    queue.add(color3); //adding color3 should automatically remove color1 from the queue. 
    //So the queue should now only contain 'color2' and 'color3'
```

Does Java have a built in Collection for this type of operation? Or do I need to build it myself?

Comment: It should be simple enough to implement. You could just extend some existing implementation and override `add` method to handle removing the head. No additional dependencies required.

Comment: This question is already answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably looking for the  [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html)  from Apache Commons 4.x, which has a fixed size and silently removes elements to make room for new elements. This is from the doc:

> CircularFifoQueue is a first-in first-out queue with a fixed size that replaces its oldest element if full.
>
> The removal order of a CircularFifoQueue is based on the insertion order; elements are removed in the same order in which they were added. The iteration order is the same as the removal order.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I am going to use `EvictingQueue` from the Guava library, which seems to do the same thing. I will accept this answer though as it pointed me in the right direction!
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html