# Extending a non-generic class to a generic class

Tags: java, list, collections, queue

The Java class CircularFifoBuffer in the package org.apache.commons.collections.buffer is non-generic, and can store objects of any class.

I would like to create a generified version of this, that can only hold objects of class T. My first thought was to extend CircularFifoBuffer and simply write a new 'add' method:

```
public class CircularFifoQueue<T> extends CircularFifoBuffer {

    public boolean add(T data) {
        return super.add(data);
    }    

}
```

However, this leaves the old 'add' method in place, allowing for objects of arbitrary class to be added. Is there a way around this that uses inheritance rather than composition (so that I don't have to re-implement all of CircularFifoBuffer's methods) but prevents users of the class from adding non-T objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is t implement your own buffer that just wraps the original one:

```
public class CircularFifoQueue<T> { 
  private CircularFifoBuffer buffer = new CircularFifoBuffer();

  public boolean add(T data) {
     return buffer.add(data);
  }    

  // implement all other methods that are needed
}
```

So the internal buffer takes everything but the wrapper makes sure that only `T` type objects can be added. Problem: right now the buffer does not implement any interface. So it's usage is a bit limited right now (you can't use it if you need to send a `Buffer` for example)

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I've decided to go with. I've also implemented `Queue<T>` to have access to those methods. The only problem is that I'd like the `add(T t)` method to return the object that drops off the end of the queue, and this doesn't seem possible within the confines of the `Queue<T>` interface. At the moment I've just created a new method `addAndRetrieve(T t)` which does what I want, although I'd be interested in hearing other solutions.

Comment: Good one! I would just also like CircularFifoQueue to implement Queue.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

The simple reason why this isn't possible is polymorphism. If you could remove the `add(Object)` method, you would break polymorphism for the `CircularFifoBuffer` class.

Here is a simple example. For this to work correctly, your `CircularFifoQueue` class needs to have a `add(Object)` method.

```
CircularFifoBuffer buffer = new CircularFifoQueue<String>();
buffer.add(new Object());
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So the only solution is to use composition, and re-implement all of the necessary methods?

Comment: Have a look at the Delegation pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern It would work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

@Vivien's answer already explains why it doesn't really make sense to do this (for more information, read about the [*Liskov substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

However, you could hack around this by defining a custom override of `add(Object)` that simply throws an exception at run-time.  It's not a very elegant solution, but if you want a quick fix, then this might be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach. It is not very elegant, but it should do the job:

```
public class CircularFifoQueue<T> extends CircularFifoBuffer {
    private Class<T> klass;
    public CircularFifoQueue(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;           
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object data) {
        T typedData = klass.cast(data);
        return super.add(typedData);
    }

    public boolean add(T data) {
        return super.add(data);
    }            
}
...
CircularFifoQueue<String> queue = new CircularFifoQueue<String>(String.class);
queue.add("hello"); // should work
queue.add(123L); // should throw ClassCastException
```

Anyway, implementing a class that delegates its method calls is not very hard. Any decent IDE will autogenerate that for you.