# Assigning a size to a Deque in Java

Tags: java, deque, arraydeque

I'm having trouble assigning a limit to the size of my double ended queue (Deque). It seems that my queue never gets full and just resizes whenever I add or offer a value unto it. My simple code just accepts a string value, splits it by space " ", loops everything and adds it to the queue.

```
evaluate("A B C D E F");

public static int evaluate(final String input){
    final Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>(3);
    final String[] tokens = input.split(" ");


    for (String token:tokens){
        System.out.println(stack.offer(token));
    }

    System.out.println(stack.size());
 }
```

returns:

```
 true
 true
 true
 true
 true
 true
 6
```

I was expecting that the queue will be full since I have not removed or read any value from it. Is there something that I'm missing here? Or am I just using the queue wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are missing reading the Javadoc - `Resizable-array implementation of the Deque interface. Array deques have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support usage`.

Comment: I see, any suggestions if there are any types of queue that implement that kind of characteristic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to implement your own class with desired behaviour. Otherwise already exists classes that remove the excessive elements. See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699069/228358

Comment: @Juni please vote up my answer if you find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>(3);
```

3 is not the size but the initial capacity as the doc explains [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#ArrayDeque-int-)

the ArrayDeque can grow as much as you need, and you are not limiting the size with that parameter in the constructor.

---

you can handle a work around dont exposing the array but instead checking everytime you want to add/offer an object in the deque

```
if (stack.size()<3) {
    stack.offer(token);
}
```

Comment: oh I see, well if that's the case, do you know of any way to limit the size of the ArrayDeque?