# What is the best data structure to save a list of last 10 objects sorted by time

Tags: java, android

I need a data structure queue, linked list of hash map or stack, to be able to save last 10 objects of user data, and if user try to add item number 11 it should delete item number 0, and make sure the list is only have the last 10 items.

Is there any library or algorithm to achieve that or I have to implement the algorithm by myself?

Comment: If your data doesn't hold duplicates you can use [TreeSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet)

Comment: it should have no duplicates

Comment: See [is-there-a-fixed-sized-queue-which-removes-excessive-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963806/is-there-a-fixed-sized-queue-which-removes-excessive-elements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [TreeSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet)

By default a TreeSet is orderd by the natural ordering of the elements you put, but can also pass your own [Comparator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E))

You can always check if your Set is at full capacity in your case [size()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet.html#size()) == 10

Then if you need to add an 11th element, first you can [pollFirst()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet#pollFirst()) or [pollLast()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet#pollLast()), then [add()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet#add(E)).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [EvictingQueue](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) from Google Guava library. According to docs:

> An evicting queue must be configured with a maximum size. Each time an
>   element is added to a full queue, the queue automatically removes its
>   head element.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own caching mechanism quite easily using a `LinkedHashMap`.

With this in mind you can create a new cache object backed by a `LinkedHashMap` that will have it's `removeEldestEntry` overridden, to check for the condition you want.

Since `removeEldestEntry` gets called every time you invoke `put` and `putAll` this will automitically refresh your cache and remove the unwanted entries.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - no third party library needed, and there's already a special method for that.