# How to create a LinkedList consists of two separate classes?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I've three classes: `Account.java`, `Transaction.java` and `StudentPrint.java` (this last one is the main class). I need to create a linked list with a list of the **Account** class and **Transaction** class inside of the main class: **StudentPrint**. Also I need to have a list of last 6 transactions inside of the **Account** class.

There might be other ways to do this, but I have requirements is do it as the described way.  I have 3 classes one of them being the class where I have the main method. I need to have an account class, a transaction class. Within the class account I need have the attributes of the student and in the transaction class the transaction type (pop-up, print) and transaction amount and transaction data and time and I need to have a linked list so that within the class account I can have a method that hold the last 6 transactions that a student did.

Comment: 1) It is not clear to me what is the question. 2) Many of the comments add nothing to the code and should be deleted.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne I have 3 classes one of them being the class where I have the main method. I need to have an account class, a transaction class. Within the class account I need have the attributes of the student and in the transaction class the transaction type (pop-up, print) and transaction amount and transaction data and time and I need to have a linked list so that within the class account I can have a method that hold the last 6 transactions that a student did.

Comment: What is oTransaction? Why is it needed? You are not limiting the transaction list to 6.

Comment: Maybe @Asaf can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from the details you provided, I assume what you're looking for is a Data-Structure to manage those last 6 transactions.

One, that's designed for this problem, is called "**Fixed-Sized Circular Queue**".

Check out these 2 Stack Overflow links for implementation examples or other ideas:

[Is there a fixed sized queue which removes excessive elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963806/is-there-a-fixed-sized-queue-which-removes-excessive-elements)

[Size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java/14322473)

.

It should be implemented like this:

```
public class Account {
    private int studentId;
    ...
    CircularFifoQueue<Integer> lastTransactions = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(6);
}

public class StudentPrint {
    LinkedList<Account> accountList = new LinkedList<Account>();
}
```

Comment: You should hold an instance of this fixed(6)-size queue in every Account.

And have a list of Accounts inside the main class. (You've already implemented the last part I've noticed)

Comment: Hello @Milky.Thank you for reply me. I need to have a LinkedList. Inside the class Account I have to have an ArrayList of the Transaction class. ArrayList <Transaction>... and in the main class I have to implement the LinkedList of the Account class. Ok I know, but how do I insert the ArrayList <Transaction> data into the LinkedList <Account> because I can insert only the class Account object, but I can not enter the transaction. If I try to print the LinkedList only returns me the attributes of the account class. And if I do LinkedAccountList.add (objAcc, arrayListTransaction) returns error.

Comment: You're welcome, @DViga. 
You need to add a field of ArrayList<Transaction> inside Account class, just like you need a field of LinkedList<Account> inside your main class.

Comment: I've add code example to the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Hi @Milky I tried do that, but when I try import import org.apache.commons.collections4.BoundedCollection, it return error "package org.apache.... do not exist.