# java.awt.Queue cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, compiler-errors, queue

The version of java: SDK 1.8.0_151

IDE: IDEA IntelliJ

```
import java.awt.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SimpleMovingAverage {
    private final Queue<Double> window = new LinkedList<Double>();
    private final int period;
    private double sum;

    public SimpleMovingAverage(int period) {
        assert period > 0 : "Period must be a positive integer";
        this.period = period;
    }

    public void newNum(double num) {
        sum += num;
        window.add(num);
        if (window.size() > period) {
            sum -= window.remove();
        }
    }

    public double getAvg() {
        if (window.isEmpty()) {return 0.0;} // technically the average is undefined
        return sum / window.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] testData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
        int[] windowSizes = {3, 5};
        for (int windSize : windowSizes) {
            SimpleMovingAverage ma = new SimpleMovingAverage(windSize);
            for (double x : testData) {
                ma.newNum(x);
                System.out.println("Next number = " + x + ", SMA = " + ma.getAvg());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is coming from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Simple_moving_average#Java

When I create a Class, called SimpleMovingAverage and copy the code from the above website, an error is reported.

> 'java.awt.Queue' is not public in 'java.awt'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

**How to solve it?**

Comment: Original source, line 2

Comment: The link you provided does not import `java.awt.Queue`. That error is yours alone.

Comment: I would appreciate clarifications on downvote. This question is neither duplicated or asked poorly. It is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `java.util.Queue` not `java.awt.Queue`, which can hold whatever you want

The `java.awt` package is about UI, graphics and images: [`Documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html), and the `java.awt.Queue` is here to hold `java.awt.Event` elements

---

**For Improvement ONLY** : for the implementation of a Circular FIFO, here some infos

- [Is there a fixed sized queue which removes excessive elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963806/is-there-a-fixed-sized-queue-which-removes-excessive-elements/21699069#21699069)
- [Basic implem of a CircularQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963806/is-there-a-fixed-sized-queue-which-removes-excessive-elements/21699069#51923797)

Which could give something like

```
public void newNum(double num) {
    window.add(num);
}
```

Comment: You keep breaking the `newNum()` method.

Comment: *If* he uses a `CircularQueue`, wherever he's going to find that. He's having enough trouble finding `java.util.Queue`. I fail to see the relevance. This is a simple import problem. Don't gussy it up.

Comment: You don't know who downvoted, let alone why, but there have been enough mistakes and irrelevance in this answer to justify a downvote.

Comment: @user207421 So there'is no place for mistakes, improvement and goodwill ? Ok nice