# Fixed-length Queue which removes first element when an element is appended at end (FIFO)

Tags: python, queue

Is there any implementation of such a queue in Python which has a fixed length, and when full, pops the left-most element while appending one to the right?

Suppose `q = Queue([1,2,3,4,5])` is my queue with a **maximum length of 5**, and I say `q.append(6)`, then expected output for `print(q)` should be `Queue([2,3,4,5,6])`

This question could also be linked to: [Is there a fixed sized queue which removes excessive elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963806/is-there-a-fixed-sized-queue-which-removes-excessive-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I have tried using `collections.deque()` and `queue.Queue()`, and `deque` is such an implementation

```
d = deque(maxlen=5)
d.extend([1,2,3,4,5])
print(d)
# deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], maxlen=5)
d.append(10)
print(d)
# deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 10], maxlen=5)
```