# Trying to understand PriorityQueue

Tags: java

I've tried looking at many websites, such as:

[How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

[Java PriorityQueue with fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846225/java-priorityqueue-with-fixed-size)

but they don't seem to answer my question.

More specifically, I'm trying to implement a custom Priority Queue where I can only have a zero/1 argument constructor that can be either `zero`/`capacity`/`p-queue`object. Is this possible considering the thread

[How do I use a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue)

talks about a 2-arg constructor (`capacity`, `comparator`)?

Added: Are the values of P-Queue always stored and retrieved as a binary tree? Wouldn't they always be sorted already then? e.g. `[5, 6, 6, 64, 9]`

Comment: You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Comment: The queue **is** the heap. They are not two distinct things.

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter Thanks. I did look at that but I still have some questions. For example, the top answer focused on a 2-arg constructor, but is it possible to just use a 1-arg constructor where the argument is the same object type (P-Queue) instead of using a comparator object?

Comment: You don't need the comparator if your queue objects implements comparable. For this kind of questions the javadocs are a great resource: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regarding constructors

`PriorityQueue` already have a zero argument constructor. You can see this yourself
easily if you read the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). Whether or not this suits your purpose I can't say. It
does require that you use a type that implements comparable (e.g. String, Integer)
otherwise the queue will have no way of knowing how to order the elements.

`capacity` in the case of `PriorityQueue` is not a max capacity, but just a hint about
how many elements you think will be in the queue at the same time. It has only performance
implications, the semantics of they queue are completely independent of this.

## Storage and retrieval semantics

The values are stored (inserted) in any order but are retrieved in order. That is the
point of a priority queue. A list that is automatically sorted every time you append to
it will give you exactly the same semantics as javas `PriorityQueue`. The list implementation would be very inefficient thought, so that's why you use a heap instead.

I'm not sure if this is a response to what you are asking, so if it's not please
clarify what you are confused about.

Comment: Thanks. My task is to implement P-Queue with 0/1/2 args for a constructor so I guess I'll have to implement them in a variety of ways. For the storage and retrieval part, I see that P-Queue adds elements to the back of the list, but when I offer(element), it somehow reorders the arrangement of the list after removing that element. Is this how P-Queue works?

Comment: It doesn't work with a list at all, but the semantics are the same as reordering the list after each insert, not after each poll. I think offer and add are synonyms in the case of priority queue.

Comment: If your task is to implement a priority queue perhaps you shouldn't think to much about how the standard one is implemented.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should just ask, which is the best way to implement add/remove/peek? Should add() sort the array immediately so remove can remove the first element, or should add() just add it to the front and remove/peek will traverse to find the highest priority element? Which one is the best way to do it?

Comment: Neither, the best way is to use a heap. Furthermore, if this is something like a school assignment then I doubt a sorting list solution will be accepted.